# CursorAdapter adapts to the wrong fields

Tags: android, android-layout, simplecursoradapter

I subclassed SimpleCursorAdapter for displaying a list. In my row layout file, I have 3 textView, but I just want to map the data to 2 of them. I explicitly left out txt2, but it keeps being displayed with the data on it. I can fix this by manually removing txt2 from the layout file, then all good. But just out of curiosity, what was wrong with the adapter in the fist place?
Tks.

```
        String []from = new String[] {
                DbField.FIELD1,
                //DbField.FIELD2,
                DbField.FIELD3

        };
        // Fields on the UI to which we map
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txt1, /*R.id.txt2,*/ R.id.txt3  };
        adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this.getActivity()
              , R.layout.row_entry, null, from,
                to, 0);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: we'd would have to see the inside of the adapter.